# Scroll to top button not working in chrome or safari

Tags: javascript

Trying a simple scroll to top button, using javascript, following the usual suggestions, works fine in firefox, can't get it to work in safari or chrome.

the code:

html:

```
<a href="#top" id="backToTopBtn" class="btn btn-info custom-top-footer-btn" >Top</a>
```

javacsript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#backToTopBtn').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

It works for me in jsfiddle in chrome and safari, so it shouldn't be the actual code: http://jsfiddle.net/m0cvsotL/

In my code, I have tried deleting all other javascript, but with no luck. Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Is everything else in your javascript/jquery working correctly?

Comment: Do you have jquery library referenced?

Comment: All the other Javascript is working and yes, I have a jquery library referenced.

Answer (score 0):

open you page in chrome, and right click Inspect Element, go to the console tab, then click your Top Link, also , try this below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#backToTopBtn').on('click',function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
return false;
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: if anything goes wrong, you should see it in the console tab

Comment: thanks for the instructions, don't normally use chrome so good to know the function. However, when I click on the top button, nothing comes into the console at all

Comment: i think maybe you html mock up is wrong,check it, you html structure, id names

Comment: would that explain it working in firefox and not chrome/safari?

Comment: just checked as well...none of the javascript I have is showing up in the console when clicked - even the items that work.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this one out eventually - I had css code to try to fix a footer in place that was obstructing the javascript. Taking it out fixed the issue totally.

I read elsewhere about scrollTop not working when there is an element with absolute positioning. The offending issue was a footer with:

```
position:absolute;
```