# Back to top scroll jquery is not working in chrome. Why. Its works fine in firefox

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/gilbitron/Lt2wH/

it work when i open in chrom browser. but not in my project. am using bootstrap css and js file.

```
if ($('#back-to-top').length) {
var scrollTrigger = 100, // px
    backToTop = function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > scrollTrigger) {
            $('#back-to-top').addClass('show');
        } else {
            $('#back-to-top').removeClass('show');
        }
    };
backToTop();
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    backToTop();
});
$('#back-to-top').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 700);
});
```

}

Some have answer it in the link [Scroll to top button not working in chrome or safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889583/scroll-to-top-button-not-working-in-chrome-or-safari). but not works for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you double check your code indentation? --- Although, your fiddle example works in my Chrome (v53)

Comment: Also, lines 12-14 can be simplified to `$(window).on('scroll', backToTop)`

Answer (score 0):

You should place your js inside the $(document).ready() function. Like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if ($('#back-to-top').length) {
     var scrollTrigger = 100, // px
     backToTop = function () {
         var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
         if (scrollTop > scrollTrigger) {
             $('#back-to-top').addClass('show');
         } else {
             $('#back-to-top').removeClass('show');
         }
     };
     backToTop();
     $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        backToTop();
     });
     $('#back-to-top').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 700);
     });
  }   
});
```